# UITableView removing checkmark from cell on search

Tags: objective-c

I am using a `UITableView` to display some items and i have implemented a `UISearchBar` to this `UITableView`.

If the user presses the cell, a checkmark appears (accessory type of the cell is changed) and when pressed again the checkmark accessory disappears.

My problem is when the user searches using the search bar, all the checked cells are not checked anymore, no more checked cells at all.

I've been trying to fix this and searching for it for a while but no results ...

Any help ??

Thanks you.

Comment: posting some code may helps you to get quick responses? we dont know your checkboxes implementations

Comment: its not a checkbox .. its the native checkmark of ios as i said in the text ... the accessory type @Codecracker

Comment: You should add your cellForRowAtIndexPath method and the logic based on which you are adding and removing the checkmarks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because your table view where you put the checkmarks and the table view that you see after you enter something in the search bar is not same. To have the same check marks on the search table view cells, you need to explicitly add the checkmarks.

I can't see the way you are adding and removing check marks. So, in theory, what you need is a way to know which cells have check marks. So, let's assume you have an array of items and a parallel array which holds the 1 or 0 to signal if the items have the check marks when 1 means check marked and 0 means no check mark.

Let's call this parallel array, checkMarkSignalArray. Now, in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, you can do something like-

```
if(self.resultSearchController.active){
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.filteredItemsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if([self.checkMarkSignalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]){
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
}
```